# IF with parameter inside native query

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a question. If I happen to do a native query, and need to do an if within it using a parameter that will come in the call, something like this:

```
   case 
      when :var=1 then 
      inner join" +
     primeiroInnerJoin
     else " +
   inner join
   segundoInnerJoin
end
```

The ":var" is a variable that will come in the call of my native query, how do I check the value of this variable and change the query depending on the value of the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make this a stored procedure call and use dynamic SQL in the database to build the query conditionally. I don't think you can have different conditional join conditions like that in SQL.

Comment: Tks friend, o try another soluction. 
I ENTERED A VALIDATION BEFORE CALLING QUERY, BUT I HAD TO LEAVE TWO QUERYS ALMOST EQUAL ONLY CHANGING THE INNER JOIN THAT I WOULD LIKE TO PUT AS DYNAMIC